# What is 'NoClassDefFoundError: clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce' while running Storm topology?

Tags: apache-storm

When I try to run the word counting topology as `storm jar wordcount.jar words.txt`, I get the below error:

My topology is as below:

Why I might be getting this error? I'm using storm-0.8.2 an external jar and have Storm 0.8.2 installed.

Comment: Read the stack trace again please: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: streaming.words.txt" Does it ring a bell?

Comment: @Chiron should be an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the stacktrace again please:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: streaming.words.txt

Does this ring a bell? Check your setup again.

Answer (score 0):

Holy smokes, gcj? Clojure requires an actual java runtime environment, 1.5+. I have never found gcj to be good for much of anything, but especially I'm certain it can't run Clojure.